# Is consistency with the $\omega$-rule absolute to $\omega$-models?

Tags: logic, model-theory, fake-proofs, proof-theory, incompleteness

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#%CF%89-logic), a theory $T$ that interprets arithmetic is consistent with the $\omega$-rule if and only if it has an $\omega$-model. That would mean that consistency with the $\omega$-rule is not absolute to a minimal $\omega$-model of $T$ (that is, a model of $T+\text{"there is no $\omega$-model of T"}$; <s>[such a model exist if $\omega$-models exist](https://mathoverflow.net/a/153276/352898))</s>.

However, it appears that consistency with the $\omega$-rule is expressible as a schema of arithmetical sentences. We can arithmetize provability by at most $n$ applications of the $\omega$-rule as $Pr^{\omega,n}_T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ (we use Quine quotes to denote Gödel numbers of formulas), defined recursively by $Pr^{\omega,0}_T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \equiv Pr_T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$ (the arithmetized provability relation),
$$Pr^{\omega,n+1}_T(\ulcorner \forall n \phi(n) \urcorner) \equiv \forall n \exists \ulcorner \psi \urcorner (\text{$\psi$ is has one free variable} \wedge Pr_T(\ulcorner \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \psi \Rightarrow \phi(n) \urcorner) \wedge Pr^{\omega,n}_T(\ulcorner \forall m \psi \urcorner)$$
and $Pr^{\omega,n}_T(\ulcorner \exists n \phi(n) \urcorner) \equiv \exists n Pr^{\omega,n}_T(\ulcorner \phi(n) \urcorner)$ From this definition we can arithmetize consistency with the $\omega$-rule as the schema $\forall \ulcorner \phi \urcorner Pr^{\omega,n}_T(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner) \Rightarrow \neg Pr_T(\ulcorner \neg \phi \urcorner)$, where $n$ ranges over the natural numbers in the metatheory. Since this is schema of arithmetical sentences, it should be absolute to any $\omega$-model of second-order arithmetic with a truth predicate for arithmetical truth.

Where does this reasoning go wrong?

Comment: I don't think the $\omega$ formula is expressible by a set of arithmetical sentences since it requires the predicate $N$ (is a natural number). But if such a predicate were expressible by a first order logic sentence one could make a categorical theory with infinite model which is not possible by Skolem ( the theory would be that with $\forall x N(x)$)

Comment: How do you know such a "minimal $\omega$-model" exists?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think a Mathoverflow answer by Andres Caicedo said that "there is an $\omega$-model of $T$ forms a hierarchy of theories but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @aldodecristo I don't see why we'd need a predicate for metatheoretical natural numbers. Wouldn't a predicate for the numbers in the model be enough since we're restricting our attention to $\omega$-models?

Comment: Caicedo's answer you linked said nothing about the existence of the minimal $\omega$-model.

Comment: @HanulJeon Caicedo said that $\text{"There is an $\omega$-model"}$ forms a hierarchy of strengthenings of any given theory (of second order arithmetic), which implies that a theory $T+\text{"there is an omega-model of $T$"}$ is stronger than $T$, but since "stronger" may not be in a semantic sense, I can't refute your objection.

Comment: $T+\text{"there is an omega-model of $T$"}$ is stronger than $T$ but that only means that $T+\text{"there is no omega-model of $T$"}$ has a model, not that it has an $\omega$-model.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I see. Could you or Hanul Jeon expand these comments into an answer (if it is indeed true that there are no minimal $\omega$-models)?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have posted [a separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605893/omega-model-hierarchy-of-theories) inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only consistency with the $\omega$-rule with finite nesting depth is expressible by a scheme of arthmetical sentences. What I was missing was that the $\omega$-rule can be applied with infinite nesting depth, as described by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5393): if for every $n$ the sentence $\phi (n)$ follows from the omega-rule with nesting depth $n$, then $\forall n \phi (n)$ follows from the omega-rule with nesting depth $\omega$; if for every $n$ the sentence $\phi (n)$ follows from the omega-rule with nesting depth $\omega$, then $\forall n \phi (n)$ follows from the omega-rule with nesting depth $\omega +1$, and so on.