# Omega model hierarchy of theories

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

According to [this Mathoverflow answer by Andres Caicedo](https://mathoverflow.net/a/153276/352898), there is a hierarchy of theories $U_\alpha$ where $U_{\alpha+1}= U_\alpha+\text{"There is an $\omega$-model of $U_\alpha$"}$, that is, $U+\text{"There is an $\omega$-model of $U$"}$ is stronger than $U$ for theories $U$ in the hierarchy. The example in the post was $U_0=ZFC$ but I assume that it applies to every recursive theory that can interpret enough second-order arithmetic.

But what does that mean semantically? Does it mean that there are minimal $\omega$-models, that is, $\omega$-models of $U_0+\text{"There is no $\omega$-model of $U_1$"}$, and more generally, are there $\omega$-models of $U_{\alpha}+\text{"There is no $\omega$-model of $U_{\alpha+1}$"}$? That is relevant to [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438218/is-consistency-with-the-omega-rule-absolute-to-omega-models). I assumed that there are minimal $\omega$-models but comments by Hanul Jeon and Eric Wofsey said that it doesn't follow from Caicedo's answer.

Comment: What does it mean that "what does it mean semantically" in your question? What do you want to ask about in your question? You asked for a semantic interpretation of something, but you did not clearly depict the thing you wanted to ask.

Comment: So, for example, you may ask "What is a model of $U_0$ that does not satisfy $U_1$?" Your question lacks such clarity.

Comment: @HanulJeon I already gave a special case of the question I mean, but I've clarified the question in more generality. But your suggested question is also good.